# @media query not working in specific css file

Tags: css

I have this weird problem and I can't figure out a solution.

My html file loads three stylesheets.

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/common.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/admin.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/navbar.css">
```

and I have the exact same @media query in both admin.css and navbar.css

admin.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
   html {display: none;} /*<-- Just for testing purposes*/
}
```

navbar.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    body 
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .navlinks
    {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 40vh;
        width: 100vw;
        top: 7vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        z-index: 99;
        background-color: var(--background);
        padding: 0.75em;
        align-items: center;
        transform: translate(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.25s ease-in;
    }

    .navlinks a
    {
        font-size: 2.25em;
    }

    .burger
    {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 3vh;
    }

    .show
    {
        transform: translate(0%);
    }
}
```

The @media query in navbar.css works but the one in admin.css doesn't.

I have tried just loading admin.css (did not fix it)
I also tried different media querys, they worked in navbar.css but not in admin.css.

Comment: Please add the folders structure to your post

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two separate media queries set to the same width "768px"
if your "navbar" media query is below the "admin" media query then specificity will apply and i believe the "admin" media query will just get ignored. why not put  html {display: none;} /*<-- Just for testing purposes*/ in with the same "768p" breakpoint? you can also try to add !important at the end of the html {display: none !important;}

Comment: I ended up creating another css file wich i loaded after admin.css and that worked. No idea why it wouldnt work in admin.css.